# How to check if JOptionPane input contains an int or double with 2 if statements and is converted?

Tags: java, swing, validation, integer, double

I would like to check if a `JOptionPane` input dialog containing the text "Enter a number" is an int or double with two if statements. Then I want to convert the int in one if statement and do the same thing in the other with a double and print "The number is" (something). If the user inputs 5 then I expect it to print an integer and if the user inputs 5.3 then I expect a double. Here is my code so far and if you test it you will see it does not work in terms of what I want it to do, but it runs:

```
    int number1Int = 0;
    double number1Double = 0.0;
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");


    if(number1Int == Integer.parseInt(num1)){
        number1Int = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is " + number1Int);
    }
    else if(number1Double == Double.parseDouble(num1)){
        number1Double = Double.parseDouble(num1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is " + number1Double);
    }
```

Comment: and what is your actual question?

Comment: Timothy Truckle, if you try the code you'll see it doesn't work, now read the question above. I want to know what condition is correct for the conversion to run and If I need to change how it is being converted.

Comment: Note that *"what condition is correct for the conversion to run?"* is a statement of inquiry known as a question. To properly mark a question, end it with the question mark '?'. So @TimothyTruckle is correct in that there is actually no question above, though you almost managed to ask one in the comment (all but lacking a '?'). Given this is a Q&A site, it is advisable to form and ask an explicit question on every post, as comments to the effect "this doesn't work"* might result in several different questions, and each thread should concentrate on just one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hello Andrew Thompson, When I said the code doesn't work I meant in terms of what I want it to do instead of compiling. Also for the statement I said that can be asked as a question it was to clarify what it was. I had trouble putting a short and simple question for my problem because it takes a bit to explain in my opinion, so if you have a better one I'd be happy to change it so people in the future with a similar problem can find it.

Comment: *"I had trouble putting a short and simple question for my problem because it takes a bit to explain in my opinion,"* Explaining a problem may take some time, but asking a question related to the failure should not. *"Why doesn't it work?"*, *"How do I fix the problem?"* or *"Are there better approaches?"* are all short questions that can follow a long explanation. If you cannot form a short question in response to a complex problem, it's a good sign you don't understand the complex problem very well (let alone the solution to it).

Comment: "If you cannot form a short question in response to a complex problem, it's a good sign you don't understand the complex problem very well (let alone the solution to it)." That is why I am asking the question Andrew Thompson. There is a reason why this is a Q/A site. Also if you want me to meet your fine question criteria why don't you correct my original question by giving me one I can put to ensure 100% quality and user satisfaction. I don't see how asking "Why doesn't it work?" is an accurate question including "How do I fix the problem?" That will not work well on a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't exactly ask a question, but I see a problem with your code that I think might be what you're having trouble with.

You have `if(number1Int == Integer.parseInt(num1))` which is only true if the user enters an integer value that is equal to `number1Int`. Since `number1Int` is initialized to 0 the only time this condition is true is when the user enters a form of zero that will parse to an integer value like 0, 00, 000, etc.

Similarly you also have `else if(number1Double == Double.parseDouble(num1))` which is only true when the user enters some form of zero that parses to a double value - could be 0.0, 0.00, 0000.000000 etc.

What I'm guessing you want is something more like this:

```
    int number1Int = 0;
    double number1Double = 0.0;
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");

    //EDIT: added boolean flag per comments
    boolean isInt = false;
    try{
        number1Int = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        isInt = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is " + number1Int);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("User did not enter an integer.");
    }
    if(!isInt){
        try{
            number1Double = Double.parseDouble(num1);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is " + number1Double);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("User did not enter a double.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and when I enter an integer it will print what it is, for example, 5 then it will print 5.0. It does not print a message. If I enter a double it will run and print the number including the message "User did not enter an integer." I was trying to enter a number and have it printed either as an integer or double not both. For example, The user entered 7, then the program ends, or The user entered 5.6 then the program ends.

Comment: Also I apologize for my question being vague I was not sure how to fit my problem without it getting very long.

Comment: Simply add a boolean flag then inside the first try block set to true. Then before the second try block add a condition to check the flag - if false do the second try

Comment: @EastAPOLO I added the boolean to the answer, see latest edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help I just added mine and tested it before I saw this and it works including your version as well.